# как исключить строку

Tags: python

```
gaz = int(input("Скільки метрів кубічних газу ви використовуєте в місяць? "))

try:
    gaz = int(input())
except ValueError:
    print("Ви ввели не число!")
    gaz = 0

res = (gaz * 8)

print ("Ваш рахунок: " + str(res) + " гривень")
```

Comment: Какую строку? Откуда исключить? Задай вопрос так, чтобы он был понятен не только тебе, но и всем остальным.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то выглядеть Ваш код должен следующим образом:

```
while True:
    try:
        gaz = int(input("Скільки метрів кубічних газу ви використовуєте в місяць? "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Ви ввели не число!")

res = (gaz * 8)

print(f"Ваш рахунок: {res} гривень")
```